# Localized output from Eureka?

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

Is there any way to localize all the output from Eureka?

The main problem I'm facing right now is to change text in the CountDownRow. I'd like to change to output in the row. I'v not found a way to edit the "hour" and "min" text

Ignore the optional labels. I think that is a separate issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello to make Localizable the countDownCell, you must make your own subclass because this seems to be an error on framework implementation, but making a subclass like this

```
//
//  MyCountDownRow.swift
//  EurekaExamplesSwift3
//
//  Created by Reinier Melian on 2/20/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Reinier Melian. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Eureka

final class MyCountDownRow: _CountDownRow,RowType {

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        displayValueFor = { [unowned self] value in
            guard let val = value else {
                return nil
            }
            if let formatter = self.dateFormatter {
                return formatter.string(from: val)
            }
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.minute, Calendar.Component.hour], from: val)
            var hourString = NSLocalizedString("k_hour", comment: "")
            if components.hour != 1{
                hourString += "s"
            }
            return  "\(components.hour!) \(hourString) \(components.minute!) \(NSLocalizedString("k_min", comment: ""))"
        }
    }

}
```

Using your own class

```
<<< MyCountDownRow(){
                $0.title = "Spanish"
            }.cellSetup({ (dateCell, myCoutDownRow) in

            let currentDate = NSDate() as Date
            myCoutDownRow.dateFormatter?.dateStyle = .short
            myCoutDownRow.dateFormatter?.timeStyle = .short
            dateCell.row.value = currentDate
        })
```

you can handle the localization, and then defining your keys `k_hour` and `k_min` in your Localizable.string you must have this result

[image]

I hope this helps you,